# Linux use binary or decimal prefix?

Tags: partitioning, sector-size

How does Linux deal with Units? Does it use decimal or binary?

```
Decimal Prefix
name      base 10 exp   base 1000 exp     digits
kilo      10^3          1000^1            1000
mega      10^6          1000^2            1000000
giga      10^9          1000^3            1000000000


Binary Prefix
name      base 2 exp    base 1024 exp     digits
kibi      2^10          1024^1            1024
mibi      2^20          1024^2            1048576
gibi      2^30          1024^3            1073741824
```

Now if you take a look for two commands for example `du` and `fdisk` you could see the difference:

Here an example for 1TB external HDD mine:

```
$ du -sh
956G    .
```

While running `fdisk`:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
```

- So Which apps use decimal and which use binary?
- How to apply one method to the whole system and apps inside?

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad since this is very much app-dependent.

Comment: forget about app. what about Linux itself?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/) doesn't say a word about SI prefixes. Where prefixes do appear in documentation, they appear without the silly `i` (`k`, `M`, etc., instead of `ki`, `Mi`) (see [`man 5 proc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/proc.5), for example). Since [GNU tools didn't gain SI prefix support](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171845/70524) until well after Linux was released, and Linus doesn't look like someone who changes kernel code simply because a standards organization prefers different prefixes, I speculate that Linux, when it does use these prefixes, uses binary prefixes.

---

The [manpages developed as part of the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/), however, does discuss this. See [`man 7 units`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/units.7):

```
Thus, today, MB = 1000000B and MiB = 1048576B.

In the free software world programs are slowly being changed to con‐
form.  When the Linux kernel boots and says

      hda: 120064896 sectors (61473 MB) w/2048KiB Cache

the MB are megabytes and the KiB are kibibytes.
```

[Wikipedia references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#cite_note-95) this, and mailing list posts by ESR (aka Eric S. Raymond, a well-known kernel developer)  ([[1]](https://lkml.org/lkml/2001/12/20/144), [[2]](https://lkml.org/lkml/2001/12/20/198), [[3]](https://lkml.org/lkml/2001/12/22/41), [[4]](https://lkml.org/lkml/2001/12/21/136)) show that a patch changing `kB` to `KiB`, etc. in one part of the documentation, was accepted, but part of it continued to use the older variants. Thus, prefixes are binary (or are intended to be binary).

Comment: I think same as you, but still searching for some official announce...

Comment: @Maythux you could ask on the kernel mailing list for confirmation, but AFAICT, [discussions on the list](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=site%3Alkml.org+si+prefix&oq=site%3Alkml.org+si+prefix) indicate its binary.

Comment: Thanks for helping, just keeping open for sometime  seeking for more details else i'm going to mark it as asnwer

Comment: @Maythux see update.

Comment: nice work, I think i have now suitable view